# NODEJS mail sending by nodemailer - looking for the pre version 3 option

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am a bit confused about nodemailer as a simple standard solution for node JS mailing.
I see the current nodemailer ver 3.x.x costs over [$800(?!?!)](http://nodemailer.com/about/pricing/) and since I am building a module in an my MVP,  to send an email once in a while, seems to me that I need another solution.

so:

1. how do I setup an older nodemailer version (I guess pre version 3.x.x)?
2. Any examples of how to use the older version code?
3. Other working options? I tried "mailover" with gmail and gmail rejects it will alerting on "Less secure app... because it has known security problems or is out of date..." issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to install the old nodemailer version

```
npm install nodemailer@2.0.0 --save
```

Then start to code by importing nodemailer module

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();

transporter.sendMail({
   from: 'sender@address',
   to: 'receiver@address',
   subject: 'hello',
   html: '<b>hello world!</b>'
   text: 'hello world!'
});
```